# How to define a catch (absolutely) all route in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, wildcard

I would like to define a catch all all route that catches all requests.

I've tried the following route definition:

```
routes.MapRoute("CatchAll", "{*stuff}", new { controller = "Proxy", action = "Proxify", stuff = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

It catches all request as long as they doesn't contain filenames like in
`http://localhost/vault/11/Test.docx`

How can I define a route that treats everyting after the hostname as a string an passes that to my controller?

**Solution**

I've found a solution to the problem by inserting the following to my web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that by default, ASP.NET includes many modules for handling different file types. This means that if the requested resource matches one of those known files types (eg. `*.asp` or `*.aspx`) then the corresponding module will handle that request instead of the MVC one.